# How to override a playbook variable only for a single role

Tags: ansible, debian

I have a playbook like this:

```
- name: Install Services
  hosts: ['myhost']
  become: True

  environment: '{{ inventory__environment | d({})
                   | combine(inventory__group_environment | d({}))
                   | combine(inventory__host_environment  | d({})) }}'

  vars:
    # Use Python from Docker virtualenv on server
    ansible_python_interpreter: '/usr/bin/env docker-python'

  roles:
    - role: debops.netbase
      vars:
        # Use normal Python
        ansible_python_interpreter: '/usr/bin/env python'
      tags: [ 'role::netbase', 'skip::netbase' ]

  tasks:
    - name: Create Network for HTTP proxy
      docker_network:
        name: http-proxy
        internal: no
        ipam_config:
          - subnet: '172.42.0.0/24'
            gateway: '172.42.0.1'
        state: presen
    ...
```

Like stated in the comment, for the docker tasks I need to use a different python interpreter. However, the `debops.netbase` role needs to use the normal python interpreter.

With the above setting I hoped to achieve that. But what happens is:

1. the role is executed successfully using `/usr/bin/env python`
2. the first task fails because it also uses `/usr/bin/env python` instead of `/usr/bin/env docker-python`

I checked this by looking into the tmp files on the host.
When removing the vars from the roles, the interpreter is set successfully to `/usr/bin/env docker-python` (the role fails, the tasks could run successfully).

How can I get my desired result without defining for every task (there are many) a distinct vars section?

Answer (score 3):

To test this out, I created a simple module that simply returns the current Python version in use:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function  # NOQA

import sys

from ansible.module_utils.basic import AnsibleModule


def main():
    module = AnsibleModule(argument_spec={},
                           supports_check_mode=True)

    result = {'changed': False,
              'python_version': sys.version}

    module.exit_json(**result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I put the above in `library/pythonversion.py`, and then tested out your problem.

My first test, which attempts to reproduce the behavior in your question, looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3

  roles:
    - role: example
      vars:
        ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python2

  tasks:
    - name: check python version
      pythonversion:
      register: pversion_playbook

    - debug:
        msg:
          - "{{ pversion_role }}"
          - "{{ pversion_playbook }}"
```

And the `example` role looks like this:

```
---
- name: in example role
  pythonversion:
  register: pversion_role
```

And indeed, as you describe, if I use the `roles` block in my playbook then the variable is set persistently. The final `debug` task shows:

```
TASK [debug] **************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "changed": false,
            "failed": false,
            "python_version": "2.7.17 (default, Oct 20 2019, 00:00:00) \n[GCC 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)]"
        },
        {
            "changed": false,
            "failed": false,
            "python_version": "2.7.17 (default, Oct 20 2019, 00:00:00) \n[GCC 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)]"
        }
    ]
}
```

But, if instead of using the `roles` block I instead use an `include_role` task, like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3

  tasks:
    - name: include example role
      include_role:
        name: example
      vars:
        ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python2

    - name: check python version
      pythonversion:
      register: pversion_playbook

    - debug:
        msg:
          - "{{ pversion_role }}"
          - "{{ pversion_playbook }}"
```

Then we see that the value of `ansible_python_interpreter` is only set to `/usr/bin/python2` during execution of the `example` role, and reverts to its original value afterwards:

```
TASK [debug] **************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "changed": false,
            "failed": false,
            "python_version": "2.7.17 (default, Oct 20 2019, 00:00:00) \n[GCC 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)]"
        },
        {
            "changed": false,
            "failed": false,
            "python_version": "3.7.5 (default, Dec 15 2019, 17:54:26) \n[GCC 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)]"
        }
    ]
}
```